# Mu2 vs Mustache.js? Should I use the Mu2 module or the Mustache.js module for nodejs templating

Tags: node.js, mustache, mu

I've decided that I will be using Mustache for our templating engine for our nodejs project but I don't see what the differences between the Mu2 ( https://github.com/raycmorgan/Mu ) and the mustache.js ( https://github.com/janl/mustache.js ) modules are.

Usually I just check the Github network and go with the most active of the communities but they seem to both be maintained just fine.

Can anyone enlighten me on what the differences might be so that I can make an informed decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right I think i've figured out the difference, if someone could confirm that would be awesome!

I found this page http://mustache.github.com/ that seems to be separating out mustache for Javascript and Mustache for Node.js

I think the node.js version is just using some node tools for caching and rendering and all that but the Mustache.js is using pure javascript and in my case could be done in the frontend or the backend.

For Node.js i would assume that the Mu2 version will be much faster and more efficient.

Comment: It's both pure javascript, however there are some small differences: for example Mu2 automatically includes partials, Mustache requires you to pass the partials as an argument, or compile them seperately.

Comment: In the end i've actually ended up going with the handlebars module which integrates quite nicely with express and the rendering engine [https://github.com/donpark/hbs]